# How to change git config core?

Tags: git

The previous devs left the server with the project and inside gitconfig file the remote repo is private and I can't push recent changes. Is there a possibility of losses in setting a new(my) repo url with `git remote set-url ...`?

The content of .git/config:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = "url"
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking us about social conventions among developers? What is "set-url"?

Comment: @isherwood Ok, sorry. The question is about moving to new repo with no losses. (And a bit about "social conventions", but it's not the main.)

Comment: @isherwood I guess it was short for `git remote set-url ...`, but OP will maybe confirm that. (That being said, we indeed lack a lot of information here so far to give a useful answer.)

Comment: It's still not clear if you having trouble cloning/pulling from the repo or trouble writing to it, and what error message you are getting when you attempt that.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I inherited the server but it's connected to a repo where I can't commit. There's just url of that repo and default settings.

Comment: What is the information which you want us to give you, that you don't already have? We can't give you access to the private repo, or tell you exactly what it contains. We certainly can't tell you whether you "should" ask for access - we have no idea what relationship you have with the previous devs and what the social implications would be. We could try to guess what you currently have locally, but by the time you'd given us enough information to be confident, you would probably have found that out for yourself.

Comment: @IMSoP The previous devs left the server with the project and inside gitconfig file the remote repo is private and I can't push recent changes. Is there a possibility of losses in setting a new(my) repo url with git remote set-url ...?

Comment: You might benefit from finding an introduction / refresher to some git concepts; specifically, the difference between "committing" a change and "pushing" it, and the difference between "local" and "remote" repositories. You can **commit** a change without any kind of network access at all; a remote repository is just a way of **sharing** those changes between different copies.

Comment: @di3po Setting up your own git repository on a service like GitHub and pushing your changes there should not result in "losses".  Just make sure it is a private repo or get permission from the copyright holders if you want to make it public.  Also if you are doing this for work, you might check with your boss.

Comment: @DavidGrayson at least 1 not aggressive reply. Thank you, man. I think I got it.

Comment: Your question was really vague though.  Remember that you should provide enough info so a complete stranger can think about your question and provide an answer that meets all your criteria to be accepted.  And it should be about software development and not opinion-based.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I'll make a note of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push to an other remote url you can do the following:

Add a new "origin":

```
git remote add new_origin {your_url}
```

Or remove the current one and recreate it:

```
git remote remove origin
git remote add origin {your_url}
```

Then push to the remote with `git push new_origin master` or `git push origin master` depending on what option you've chosen.

This will push the `master` changes the the specified remote.

As a person al preference, I would advise you to use an other origin in order not to lose the original one..

NOTE: in your case, your request has nothing to do with the local repo config which can be changed using the `git config --help` command.